# SqlServer selected column data padded with unwanted whitespace

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, database-design, data-storage

I discovered something that I have never seen with a database engine.
There's a table in the database, lets say the table has a few nchar(50) columns. Like Firstname, Lastname.
I insert a row into the table.
Then I get the data back by selecting the row. Now the data is padded with whitespace, so it's 50 characters long.

See this! `'MyName'` becomes `'MyName                                            '`

Although I do not want this manipulative behaviour, I also think it's just unacceptable. Simply said, it just *changes* my data without my intention.

What can I do to solve this? If the answer is: just trim the strings you get from the database results, then I'm disappointed.
What if my original data *did* contain whitespaces at the end, and I don't want to loose them?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `varchar` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly what is expected:

`char/nchar` are fixed length

`varchar/nvarchar` are variable length

You should also check `SET ANSI_PADDING ON/OFF` to set how sql server handles trailing spaces in varchar columns.

`SET ANSI_PADDING ON` will not trim trailing spaces (if present) in varchar columns

`SET ANSI_PADDING OFF` will trim trailing spaces (if present) in varchar columns

Answer (score 1):

change your data type from nchar(50) to nvarchar(50).
nchar(50) will result in the number of characters of value and remaining with whitespace.
'MyName' has 6 characters so, remaining 44 characters will be whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

To quote from [`char` and `varchar` (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> - Use char when the sizes of the column data entries **are consistent**.
> - Use varchar when the sizes of the column data entries **vary** considerably.
> - Use varchar(max) when the sizes of the column data entries vary considerably, and the size might exceed 8,000 bytes.

Emphasis is mine.

If you have a `char(10)` column, then the string will be "padded" out if you use less than 10 characters. For example `'a'` stored in a `char(10)` would become `'a         '`.

When using variable sizes, use a `varchar` (the var means variable). This means that the value will not be padded out. Thus with a `varchar(10)`, `'a'` will be stored as `'a'`.